# Is there a way to have an instance of an app's taskbar icon to look different?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have several instances of an app open at the same time. One of them is the one I use most of often. I would like its taskbar icon to be easily identified on the taskbar. Is there any way to make it visually different than the other instances?
Using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  You can create a copy of the `.exe` and change the icon embedded in the `.exe`.  Here are some [instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/) on how to do it.  Then you can run the changed instance and the original instance and have two different icons.

It is possible this might not work, but since you made a copy, there should not be an issue.  Also, virus scanners may flag the changed file, but that shouldnt be an issue, as you can whitelist it.